# Can't figure out how to store outputted parameters to variables using SQL Datasource ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I'm working on an application where it requires me to find the username of the user logged in, query against an employee table where the username = active user, and then return EmployeeID, TeamID, and PositionID to set Session State variables to create different views base on each user.

I have created this stored procedure to output the needed parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ASP_UserSession @Username nvarchar(256), @UserID int OUTPUT, @TeamID int OUTPUT, @PositionID int OUTPUT

AS

SELECT @UserID = ID, @TeamID = TeamID, @PositionID = PositionID
FROM Employee
WHERE UserName = @Username
```

Now the issue I'm having is storing the outputed parameters into the code behind file in order set the parameters in Session State.

I'm about ready to pull all of my hair out! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue with this code:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    string activeuser = user.UserName;

    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sc1 =
             new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DRIFT\GANDALF;Initial Catalog=Wizard_Swears;" +
                 "Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        sc1.Open();
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
        {
            command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command1.Connection = sc1;

            // DIRECTION :: Input
            command1.CommandText = "select @UserID = [ID], @TeamID = [TeamID], @PositionID = [PositionID] FROM [Employee] WHERE ([UserName] = @UserName)";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramter1 = command1.Parameters.Add("@UserName", activeuser);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramter2 = command1.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramter3 = command1.Parameters.Add("@TeamID", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramter4 = command1.Parameters.Add("@PositionID", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            paramter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            paramter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            paramter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            paramter4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //Store values to variables to be set to session
            string userID = paramter2.Value.ToString();
            string teamID = paramter3.Value.ToString();
            string positionID = paramter4.Value.ToString();

            UserIDLBL.Text = userID;
            TeamIDLBL.Text = teamID;
            PositionIDLBL.Text = positionID;


            Session["Username"] = activeuser;
            Session["UserID"] = UserIDLBL.Text;
            Session["AMID"] = TeamIDLBL.Text;
            Session["PositionID"] = PositionIDLBL.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DbParameter` class has a `Direction` property, to which you can set a value of `ParameterDirection.Output`

After executing the stored procedure, get the parameter object from the parameters collection of the command object and get its value.

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason I can't get those output parameters to work. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Try the setting for just ParameterDirection.Output.  I've had some instances where inputoutput didn't work for me but then again I was probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh, yes, since the parameters are not used for input, set to Output

Comment: Do you have example code on how to store the output to variables in the code behind?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/02/19/examples-of-using-system-data-parameterdirection-with-sql-server.aspx

Comment: This is the error I get when using the Output example.Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName".
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName".

Source Error: 


Line 31:                 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter paramter1 = command1.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
Line 32:                 paramter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
Line 33:                 command1.ExecuteNonQuery();